# Getting error invalid command: "networkid=15"

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, geth-debugging

```
geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc networkid=15 2>&1 | tee -a blockchain.log
```

while running the above command i get following error

> invalid command: "networkid=15"

[image]

And the same command works on another server so i guess am missing something configuration wise.

[image]

Comment: I think you meant `--networkid 15`?

Comment: no,the command is same as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you get the same error when you try `--networkid 15`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just saw your edit. I don't know why that is working on the other server. Perhaps it's a different version of `geth`? I don't see any documentation that supports using `networkid=15`.

Comment: its okay @smarx thanks for giving your valuable time...let me check configuration once.